# Azure pipeline failing during AppStoreRelease

Tags: azure, azure-devops

For the AppStoreRelease I have added the Service connection for applestore and added the Fastlane session token and mentioned the same service connection in the pipeline even after that while running the pipeline its asking for the 6 digit code

(You can also set the environment variable `SPACESHIP_2FA_SMS_DEFAULT_PHONE_NUMBER` to automate this)
(Read more at: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/docs/Authentication.md#auto-select-sms-via-spaceship_2fa_sms_default_phone_number)

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/highline-1.7.10/lib/highline.rb:624: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
Please enter the 6 digit code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the warning message, when you setup the **Apple App Store service connection**, you do not provide the value of "**`App-specific Password`**".

When your Apple account has 2-factor authentication enabled, in your case, you need to provide both **`App-specific Password`** and **`Fastlane Session`** on the **Apple App Store service connection**.

[image]

To setup **`App-specific Password`** and **`Fastlane Session`**, you can reference to the article below:

[**Use of application specific passwords and spaceauth**](https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/#use-of-application-specific-passwords-and-spaceauth)